# Numpy array not updated when assigning unexpected value to dtype('int64') using math.erf()

Tags: arrays, math, numpy, int

I'm simply trying to write the output of the `math.erf()` to a numpy array.
All I'm doing is:

```
import numpy as np
import math
a=np.array([0,0,0])
a[0]=math.erf(5)
```

However, a is never updated to hold the values of the output of `math.erf()` which should simply be a float.
What am I doing wrong?

**Update**

When `a` is created from a list via `a=np.asarray(a)`, it seems to work.

Comment: Considering Craig's answer, the real problem isn't with `math.erf`.  It would be "nice" to change the question title to reflect the problem of unexpectedly assigning a small float value to an int and always getting zero.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It does get updated, but it doesn't change they type of array hence the value does not appear to change.  Notice that

```
a=np.array([0,0,0])
a.dtype
```

Returns

```
dtype('int64')
```

Since `math.erf(5)`<1 as an integer it is zero.

As an alternative (there are many ways to create an array of a particular type)

```
a=np.array([0,0,0],dtype=float)
a[0]=math.erf(5)
```

Does what you expect.